# Microsoft Excel VBA Or Function That Allows Me To Get Text After A Certain Word

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am currently trying to get the numbers after "FCC ID:" for each cell.

Example Cell:

```
Brand New Aftermarket Replacement For:
FCC ID: MYT8Z0837231
IC: 4427A-8Z0837231
Chip: MEGAMOS 48 CRYPT
Frequency: 315 MHz
Reusable: Yes 
Battery: CR2032
```

For the multiple cells that I have sadly the "FCC ID" is either lowercase or uppercase.

I have tried the function: `=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-SEARCH(":", B2))` But that only works for characters.

Comment: Investigate the VBA Split method.

Comment: In your example  MYT8Z0837231  has an 8 between the T and Z   do you want all numbers or only the numbers after the last letter?  You might check this answer about regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops